# How to make IE 9 stop reading all the fonts every time?

Tags: fonts, internet-explorer-9

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) showed me that IE 9 accesses **every time** it loads on my system, which makes it have a 1- to 2-second delay every time it loads. (I tested this by removing my fonts -- it loaded much more quickly.)

It gets a little annoying, because it's the best handler I have for MHT files, so I don't want to switch to something else.

Is there any way to make it avoid doing that? (The "Hide Fonts" feature in Windows 7 doesn't work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was recently a Windows Update in Win7 (or at least, the last time I turned Win7 on) to fix this very issue if I recall.

[KB2505438 - Slow performance in applications that use the DirectWrite API on a computer that is running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2505438), there are links to the download on the page.

Comment: +1 seemed to be a Font Cache service issue. Thanks!

Comment: In that case, is the Fontcache service running?

Comment: Oh, got to it just as I did.